# Uso do seed no R

Tags: r

Sobre o *seed*, não entendo quando usar: `seed(1)`, `seed(123)`, `seed(12345)`. Qual seria a diferença entre eles?

Comment: 1) Nenhuma diferença, pode usar qualquer um deles. 2) **Toda a diferença!** Isso serve para inicializar o gerador de números pseudo-aleatótios, sempre que quiser repetir os resultados do programa, basta usar o **mesmo valor** de `seed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença em usar números distintos no `set.seed()` é basicamente que cada vez que você usar um número diferente nos parênteses será gerado um número aleatório diferente.

Como a função do `set.seed()` é gerar números aleatórios, o valor utilizado seria uma forma de garantir que seja usado o mesmo número aleatório posteriormente, por exemplo:

Se usar a o comando `rnorm()` para gerar 10 valores amostrados aleatóriamente de uma distribuição normal poderá obter:

```
>rnorm(10)
 [1]  1.2240818  0.3598138  0.4007715  0.1106827 -0.5558411  1.7869131  0.4978505
 [8] -1.9666172  0.7013559 -0.4727914
```

repetindo o mesmo comando os valores poderiam ser:

```
> rnorm(10)
 [1] -1.0678237 -0.2179749 -1.0260044 -0.7288912 -0.6250393 -1.6866933  0.8377870
 [8]  0.1533731 -1.1381369  1.2538149
```

portanto, diferentes para mesma função. No estanto, se quiser partir do mesmo número aleatório, você pode usar a função `set.seed()`:

```
> set.seed(123); rnorm(10)
 [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774  1.71506499  0.46091621
 [8] -1.26506123 -0.68685285 -0.44566197
```

repetindo o mesmo comando com o `set.seed()` e os mesmos números dentro dos parênteses:

```
> set.seed(123); rnorm(10)
 [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774  1.71506499  0.46091621
 [8] -1.26506123 -0.68685285 -0.44566197
```

portanto, iguais, devido ter sido utilizado o mesmo número aleatório para a função `rnorm()`.

Se usasse a mesma função e "esquecesse" de colocar o 3 no comando `set.seed(123)`, poderia ter :

```
> set.seed(12); rnorm(10)
 [1] -1.4805676  1.5771695 -0.9567445 -0.9200052 -1.9976421 -0.2722960 -0.3153487
 [8] -0.6282552 -0.1064639  0.4280148
```

que seria completamente diferente.

Answer (score 5):

A função `set.seed` serve para se poder reproduzir os resultados dos geradores de números pseudo-aleatórios (RNG, na sigla em Inglês). Isto é importante para ter resultados de análise de dados em que os geradores de RNGs são usados.
Por exemplo, quando corre simulações. Ou quando quer ajustar um modelo de classificação e precisa de dois subconjuntos dos dados, um para treinar o modelo e outro para o testar.

O valor da semente não é importante desde que seja consistente na sua utilização. O que é verdadeiramente importante é que o que o programa faz possa ser reproduzido fielmente.

Veja os seguintes exemplos.
Primeiro vou criar dois vetores, `x` e `y`. Para o fazer vou usar *exatamente as mesmas instruções*. Mas os resultados são diferentes.

```
n <- 100

set.seed(12)

x <- rnorm(n)
mean(x)
#[1] -0.03116866

y <- rnorm(n)
mean(y)
#[1] 0.009693236
```

Agora vou repor o estado do gerador de números normais tal como estava imediatamente antes de criar o vetor `x`.

```
set.seed(12)

z <- rnorm(n)
mean(z)
#[1] -0.03116866

identical(mean(x), mean(z))
#[1] TRUE
```

Não são só as médias que são idênticas, são os próprios vetores `x` e `z`.

```
identical(x, z)
[1] TRUE
```

Agora um exemplo de uma técnica de reamostragem, o bootstrap. O exemplo que se segue é o primeiro exemplo de `help('boot')`.

```
library(boot)

ratio <- function(d, w) sum(d$x * w)/sum(d$u * w)

b1 <- boot(city, ratio, R = 999, stype = "w")
b2 <- boot(city, ratio, R = 999, stype = "w")

mean(b1$t)
#[1] 1.562257

mean(b2$t)
#[1] 1.560816
```

Os valores são diferentes.
Agora tornar os resultados reprodutíveis.

```
set.seed(1234)
b3 <- boot(city, ratio, R = 999, stype = "w")
set.seed(1234)
b4 <- boot(city, ratio, R = 999, stype = "w")

identical(mean(b3$t), mean(b4$t))
#[1] TRUE
```

Mais uma vez não são só as estatísticas que são iguais, são os objetos criados.

```
identical(b3, b4)
#[1] TRUE
```

Finalmente, mais uma vez note que tanto pode usar `12`, `123`, `2319` ou outro valor qualquer. Mas se usa um valor use sempre esse mesmo valor todas as vezes que correr o mesmo programa de análise ou simulação ou qualquer outro que chame os geradores de RNGs.